# Huge number of calls to ANTLR38BitConsume library function

Tags: antlr3, lexical-analysis, antlrworks

I'm writing a lexer for ASN1 using ANTLR3 for C target, using the version 3.4 of the library. Actually the lexer is really slow, so I performed a perf record on the execution, and I found that the bottleneck is the library function ANTLR38BitConsume, which is pretty simple.

```
static void
antlr38BitConsume(pANTLR3_INT_STREAM is)
{
pANTLR3_INPUT_STREAM input;


input   = ((pANTLR3_INPUT_STREAM) (is->super));

if  ((pANTLR3_UINT8)(input->nextChar) < (((pANTLR3_UINT8)input->data) +    input->sizeBuf))
{   
/* Indicate one more character in this line
 */
input->charPositionInLine++;

if  ((ANTLR3_UCHAR)(*((pANTLR3_UINT8)input->nextChar)) == input->newlineChar)
{
    /* Reset for start of a new line of input
     */
    input->line++;
    input->charPositionInLine   = 0;
    input->currentLine      = (void *)(((pANTLR3_UINT8)input->nextChar) +    1);
}

/* Increment to next character position
 */
input->nextChar = (void *)(((pANTLR3_UINT8)input->nextChar) + 1);
}
}
```

After an investigation, I have figured out that on a file with size 1.4KB, this function, which should be called at most one per bytes I think, it's called 24.5M times. Do you know if this is a known issue or if there is another explanation for this weird behaviour?

**EDITED**

After some trials, I have figured out the rules which cause this issue. I have some rules in order to recognize specific object identifiers, which are very simple:

```
 OID1 : {counter==6}?=> 2 3 4 5 840 {counter=0;}
```

and a rule which matches every byte in the content field of ASN1 encoding:

```
 VALUE : ({counter>0}?=> '\u0000'..'\u00FF' {counter--;})+
```

Since the lexer uses Longest Matching rule, OID1 will never be matched, because VALUE can match an arbitrary long value. Hence, in order to fool the lexer, I edit OID1 rule in this way:

```
OID1 : {counter==6}?=> 2 3 4 5 840 {counter=0;} VALUE?
```

The VALUE token at the end of the rule will never be matched, since that rule is active only when counter is greater than 0, but in this way the lexer will consider also OID1 in the matching, because it can be longer than VALUE. 
However, this rule caused that huge number of calls to BitConsume function! As soon as I delete the VALUE? part, I got a number of calls precisely equal to the number of bytes of input file. 
I think that this is an implementation bug of ANTLR, since it should try to match the input following OID1 with VALUE, but it should immediately stop and skip the token because counter is 0.

Comment: More likely the grammar parses too many alternatives. Like sign before numeric literal and sign as binary operator. Make test data with different constructs, and look whether differences in the profiles are of interest. (Should you parse ASN1 **binary** data newlines do not make sense.)

Comment: Yes, backtracking can have a big impact, so make sure you don't use it if possible.

Comment: Can you try it with Java? Try it and compare results. Java target it better maintained is surprisingly is faster than C one. I recall I fixed some bug in C++ target related to syntactic predicates(but you use semantic ones), the order of conditions was opposite for C/C++ target. So while other targets had in generated conditions like `if( a = x && b() == "y")`  for C/C++ this was `if( b() == "y" && a = x)` . This resulted into enormous number of calls to `b()`.

Comment: I have already written quite a lot of semantic statements in C, hence it requires a non negligible effort to switch on Java. But I think that C target has to be really bad implemented to be outperformed by Java. and apart from this issue I had, it doesn't seem this case. If I manage to handle specific OIDs, I think it will be fats enough ;) But I will also make a comparison on execution time between Java and C on simpler grammars i have, thank You for your input :)